# Error adding parameters to sql execution from c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

Sorry if someone has already given an answer to this, I have been browsing the site and trying tips and bits of code for hours, to no avail.

I have a stored procedure which basically retrieves the id of an element, if this element exists, and zero if it doesn't.

Here we go:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[ChecksProductExistence]  
        @Product_Name varchar(50),
        @Return_Value Int output
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT prod.ProductID
               FROM dbo.Products prod 
               WHERE prod.ProductName = @Product_Name)
        SET @Return_Value = 1;
    ELSE 
        SET @Return_Value = 0;
END
```

Okay, so far so good. Execute that in my database, and it works like a charm... not that it's such complex code.

Then, in Visual Studio, I coded the following:

```
private static bool checkExistingProduct(ShoppingListContext ctx, Product product)
{
    var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "[dbo].[ChecksProductExistence]";

    ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
    int bla = 0;

    SqlParameter inParameter = new SqlParameter();
    inParameter.ParameterName = "@Product_Name";
        inParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        inParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        inParameter.Value = product.ProductName;

    SqlParameter outParameter = new SqlParameter();
        outParameter.ParameterName = "@Return_Value";
        outParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
        outParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(inParameter);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outParameter);

    bla = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Console.WriteLine(outParameter.Value);

    Console.ReadLine();

    if ((int)outParameter.Value == 1) return true; else return false;
}
```

As you can see... simple enough. I create a command, add parameters, execute it, try some decision making on the output.

But... I get an error on the

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

line. I have changed it to `ExecuteScalar`, for example, but still no luck. I have executed it without the "bla = ...", and still the same.

The error I get is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Procedure or function 'ChecksProductExistence' expects parameter '@Product_Name', which was not supplied.

But then again, not only can you see clearly in the code that I AM IN FACT SUPPLYING IT, but also on the debug session I can explore the cmd object and browse the parameters, and I can see that IT IS THERE, and the values are correct...

So what else can I do?? Am I making some silly mistake I can't see...?

Comment: I think you need to set the `cmd.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: @AaronBertrand But it's calling it like a query where you have to specify the parameters in the command text like `[dbo].[ChecksProductExistence] @Product_Name @Return_Value`.  That might work, but I'd just change the command type instead.

Comment: Ya, you should just have to do:
`SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("procedureName", connectionObject)`
 then `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` then `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paramName", paramValue)` then execute.  ExecuteNonReader is for True/False statements like Inserts, Deletes or Updates. ExecuteScalar is for Procs that will return a single value like a Count.  ExecuteReader is for queries that will return row(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the documentation for [`SqlCommand.CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have to set it to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and set the `CommandText` to the name of the stored procedure.  It defaults to `CommandType.Text` where you have to include the named parameters in the text of the query.

> When you set the CommandType property to StoredProcedure, you should
>   set the CommandText property to the name of the stored procedure. The
>   command executes this stored procedure when you call one of the
>   Execute methods.
>
> The Microsoft .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL
>   Server does not support the question mark (?) placeholder for passing
>   parameters to a SQL Statement or a stored procedure called with a
>   CommandType of Text. In this case, named parameters must be used. For
>   example:
>
> SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID

So, just add the following

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

somewhere before executing it.

Comment: Wow that worked like a charm!!!! And now that I read your explanation, I do feel a bit stupid. LOL...  Thank you!!!